# Do post offices in Leipzig offer a faxing service?

Tags: germany, leipzig, services

I want to send a fax from Leipzig. I know some post offices, like Deutsche Post, but do they usually offer such service?

Do post offices in Leipzig offer sending faxes? If not, from where can I send a fax? And how much would that cost me ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Deutsche post doesn't offer such a service. Callshops and copyshops do offer sending a fax. A qiuck search in [gelbeseite.de](http://www.gelbeseiten.de/copyshop/leipzig) will show you some copyshops and almost all of them will also offer sending a fax. The price may vary from store to store. I found this [pricelist](http://m-m-copyshop-berlin.de/Preisliste.pdf) of a copyshop in Berlin (see page 13). If you send a fax to a non European country it will cost 4 EUR for the first page and 1 EUR for each next page.